# How can I send Parse push notifications to users after specific user action?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have read a lot of tutorials and doc but I cannot quite wrap my head around it: I am trying to send users of my app a notification when somebody posts something new or if someone likes one of their posts (think Facebook-style table view displaying notifications as they happen). The certificates are set up and the app is able to receive remote notifications that I send through the Parse push console.

Obviously I want to send a notification as the actions happen, but I am unsure how to do that. Parse suggests using cloud code, but it seems to be in Javascript. Is there a way to do it in Swift? My first idea was to send the push from the users' devices as they interact (when the user likes a pic from you, he sends the push and you receive it) but apparently, it is discouraged as it is unsafe.

I understand my question is general, but I am lost as to how I can tackle this issue: can anybody give me an outline of how this should be dealt with? Not necessarily precise code, but a general idea of what I should do?

Comment: What are you struggling with? Have you read the Parse blog; all the code needed is outlined ... http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/the-dangerous-world-of-client-push/

Comment: Okay so this is what I wasn't sure I understand, since I thought I had to set up Cloud Code on the Parse server in addition to the device. I think I misunderstood what cloud code meant. This code is meant to use as the action is triggered, correct?

Comment: It is possible to send push notifications to other users directly from the device based on interactions, but Parse doesn't recommend this (as it can be a security risk like if someone was able to inject data into the push being sent from your device), so they suggest instead writing the Cloud Code functions instead.

Comment: If you read the article, you'll see they give an example of the code that does need to run on the server. The function is then called from the Mobile device (again an example is given). The distinction, in the example, is that the cloud code performs addition verification (it checks to see that the recipient is the senders friend ). They list the reasons you shouldn't send a client to client push directly.